# How to add new lines from another file with sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I'm trying to find the `sed` command so that I can put `filename` into `filename1`. These are my two separate files.

INPUT `filename` has:

```
Cindy   11 22 54
Chester 48 12 84
```

INPUT `filename1` has:

```
 Name  Class1 Class2 Class3
Lee      92     94     88
Chancy   91     85     95
Dora     99     77     96


Jefferry 84     98     90
```

This is the result that I need (output):

```
Name   Class1 Class2 Class3
Lee      92     94     88
Chancy   91     85     95
Dora     99     77     96
Cindy    11     22     54
Chester  48     12     84
Jefferry 84     98     90
```

If I need to clarify anything let me know. Basically Cindy and Chester has to be right in between Dora and Jefferry.

Comment: What is the order of lines in the output?

Comment: There shouldnt be any order if i remember correctly. I'm not 100% sure, I just know that the output has to look like that. Still an amateur at this so everything is sort of new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add all lines from `filename` to `filename1` using `sed` command you can do the following:

```
sed r filename1 filename
```

Please note however that the result will be slightly different from the output in your question, namely:

```
Name  Class1 Class2 Class3
Lee      92     94     88
Chancy   91     85     95
Dora     99     77     96
Jefferry 84     98     90
Cindy    11     22     54
Chester  48     12     84
```

---

**Edit**

Some additional `sed` information useful for this question:

- To add `filename` after 4th line of `filename1`:

  `sed '4 r filename' filename1`
- To add `filename` after line which starts from "Dora" in `filename1`:

  `sed '/^Dora/ r filename' filename1`
- To add `filename` after 4th line and remove any blank lines from `filename1`:

  `sed '/^$/d;4 r filename' filename1`

Comment: Cindy and Chester has to be after Dora. I did sed r filename1 filename but Cindy and Chester are at the end of the order and theres still a space gap.

Comment: If you want the additional lines to be inserted after the line starting with `Dora` then you can do `sed '/^Dora/ r filename' filename1`

Comment: That works, but after entering that command. I need to eliminate the blank lines that are between Chester and Jefferry.

Comment: @TayshaunS See the edit of my answer.

Comment: You are a life saver, i was trying all sorts of combination of those two /^$/d and /^Dora/  r. But it kept giving me an error. Couldnt figure it out, I appreciate everyones time and help!

Comment: @TayshaunS next time, please mention the things you tried in your question. It [demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself and saves us from reiterating obvious answers]( demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers). Also when an answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and gives the answerer some well earned reputation.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Im still very new to StackExchange. So forgive me on this. I will be sure to do so next time.

Answer (score 2):

> There shouldnt be any order if i remember correctly.

In that case:

```
$ cat file2 file1 | column -t
Name      Class1  Class2  Class3
Lee       92      94      88
Chancy    91      85      95
Dora      99      77      96
Jefferry  84      98      90
Cindy     11      22      54
Chester   48      12      84
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
sed r file1 file2
```

...then `sed` will try and fail to append a `r`ead file with a null-length filename to every input line of both its named input files *`file1`* and *`file2`*. That command is essentially no different than:

```
sed '' file1 file2
```

...except that w/ `r` it is slower.

This is what I mean:

```
seq 1  5 > file1
seq 6 10 > file2
strace sed r file[12]
```

---

```
...
write("1\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write("2\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write("3\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write("4\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write("5\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
read(3, "", 4096) = 0
close(3) = 0
open("file2", RDONLY) = 3
write("6\n", 21) = 2
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write("7\n", 21) = 2
...
```

---

See the `open("" ...)` failing with *`ENOENT`* following every line written out? Thats the empty `r`ead command `sed` runs. You don't notice the failures because `sed` is spec'd not to complain about a non-existent `r`ead file named in its script, but rather to carry on as if nothing happened when it tries to `r`ead one.

And maybe it *looks* like it works because you just want to append a file to the end of another - to con`cat`enate two files - which `sed` does by default when two input files are named - it reads the first and then the next. But if the `r`ead command really worked then the named `r`ead file would be appended entirely to *every* line in input.

Like this:

```
seq 3 > file
printf %s\\n a b c | 
sed r\ file
```

---

```
a
1
2
3
b
1
2
3
c
1
2
3
```

---

To append the contents of one file to another you can do:

```
cat < file2 >> file1
```

To append after only a certain point in input you have some options. `sed` is among them:

```
sed -e '/match/{r file2' -e:n -e 'n;bn' -e \} file1
```

...which should work w/ practically any `sed`.

Or else if you have a POSIX `sed`:

```
{ sed /match/q; cat file2 -; } < file1
```

...which should be far more efficient.

Both methods ensure that the contents of *`file2`* is only `r`ead out once and only immediately following the first occurrencd of `match` in *`file1`*.

Another way could look like:

```
cat file2 | sed /match/r\ /dev/fd/0 file1
```

...which would read a null-length file out after every match following the first...